# There is virtual HID, how I can remove it

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I don't know how to remove it. Also I can't change Tracking speed for the USB mouse, only for trackpad.

[image]

Comment: You are asking two distinct questions which doesn't follow the Stack Exchange model. Please [edit] to focus on one question and post a second question for your other issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.